# Isolated coloring of math symbols and boxes in equations

Tags: color

I know that by using a package like `xcolor` I can use `$\color{<color>} <math symbols>$` to typeset math symbols in my preferred color. But how can I isolate the color to specific symbols only?

Say for instance the illustrations of commented equations in Howard Anton's Calculus book have colors for underbraces and the bounding text boxes but have none for the included text.

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d}{dx}[\sin(3x^2+2)]=\underbrace{\cos(3x^2+2)}_{\text{
\fbox{\parbox[b][]{2cm}{
Derivative of the outise evaluated at the inside}
}}}
\cdot 
\underbrace{6x}_{\text{
\color{blue}{\fbox{\parbox[b][]{1.25cm}{
Derivative of the inside}
}}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which outputs

[image]

How can I isolate the coloring to the underbraces and the bounding box to blue without affecting the other symbols/text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\underbrace[2][olive]{%
\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
$\hfil\displaystyle{#2}\hfil$\crcr
\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
\textcolor{#1}{\upbracefill}\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}
\makeatother
\newcommand\ColorBox[3][olive]{\text{\fcolorbox{#1}{white}{\parbox[b][]{#2}{\raggedright#3}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}[\sin(3x^2+2)]=\underbrace{\cos(3x^2+2)}_{\ColorBox{2cm}{Derivative of the outise evaluated at the inside}}
\cdot 
\underbrace[red!60!black]{6x}_{\ColorBox[red!60!black]{1.25cm}{Derivative of the inside}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax:

```
\underbrace[<color>]{<text>}
\ColorBox[<color>]{<width>}{<text>}
```

The default color: `olive`.

Comment: That was fast. Where can I find the definition for `\underbraces` and other such commands?

Comment: @hpesoj626 For LaTeX kernel commands, such as `\underbrace`, you can open a terminal a run `texdox source2e` or in CTAN: [source2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e).

Answer (score 4):

Here are some minor alternatives to Gonzalo's answer, provided by the [`abraces` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/abraces). More specifically, it allows for inserting arbitrary code within the brace construction using `@{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{abraces}% http://ctan.org/pkg/abraces
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\big[\sin(3x^2+2)\big]=
    \underbrace[@{\color{olive}}l1D1r]{\cos(3x^2+2)}_{\color{olive}
      \text{\fbox{\parbox[b]{2cm}{\raggedright%
        \color{black}Derivative of the outside evaluated at the inside}
  }}}
  \cdot
  \underbrace[@{\color{red!60!black}}l1D1r]{\vphantom{()}6x}_{\color{red!60!black}
    \text{\fbox{\parbox[b]{1.25cm}{\raggedright%
      \color{black}Derivative of the inside}
  }}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Other modifications include:

- Using `\mathrm{d}` for d/dx;
- Enlarging the brackets around the LHS using `\big[` and `\big]`; and
- Inserting `\vphantom` to lower the `\underbrace` for both components of the chain rule to the same depth.