# Colored underbraces for annotating equations

Tags: beamer, formatting, equations

I am trying to implement my previous Powerpoint presentation in `beamer`.

I have a figure like

[image]

I want to create something like this in `beamer`.

I wrote a equation as follows but I couldn't write the description underneath the equation as shown in figure:

```
\begin{equation}
\partial _t(m_x m_yHu)+ \partial_x(m_yHuu)+\partial_y(m_xHvu)+\partial_z(m_xm_ywu)-m_xm_yf_cHv
\end{equation}
```

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/) is not exactly what you want to do, but it may be of interest.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for your reply. In fact that post is interesting too. I will also try to implement that in my future slides. Very impressive.

Comment: Related, a previous question of mine. Just in case you are interested: [Isolated coloring of math symbols and boxes in equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74308)

Comment: Also related: [Highlight terms in equation mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118410/10102). Highlights parts of equations, not with underbraces, but with colored shading / boxes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The operator spacing is not perfect, but the braces add some horizontal padding which might be sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
  \alert{\underbrace{\color{black}\partial _t(m_x m_yHu)}_
    {\mathclap{\text{Local acceleration}}}}
  {+}
  \alert{\underbrace{\color{black}
    \partial_x(m_yHuu) + \partial_y(m_xHvu) + \partial_z(m_xm_ywu)}_
      {\text{Advective acceleration}}}
  {-}
  \alert{\underbrace{\color{black}m_xm_yf_cHv}_
    {\substack{\text{Coriolis}\\\text{acceleration}}}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Some highlights:

- `\alert` provides the colour choice for the `\underbrace`s, while `\color{black}` avoids the colour transformation of the expression.
- `\text` (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), loaded by [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) allows for easy formatting of text in sub-/superscripts without having to worry about the font sizes.
- Since the text under the first brace is wider than the math component, `\mathclap` inserts the contents in a zero-width box so as to not influence the surrounded components being set.
- `\substack` allows for stacking of elements vertically, especially as a subscript under an operator, which `\underbrace` intrinsically is.
- Surrounding the operators with braces `{<op>}` removes their "binary operator" spacing. However, the padding inserted by the `\underbrace`s (on either side) acts as a sufficient buffer. It's not perfect, but it might not be all the noticeable.

Comment: @ Werner Thank you so much for your answer and your explanations are superb. It really helps a beginner like. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

Building on Werner's solution, you can define a new command for more automation.

In the code below, I define a command called `\redub` (for "red underbrace") that uses _ as delimiter between its two arguments, just like `\underbrace`, and with which

1. juggling the two colours (red and the current colour) is not necessary,
2. hardcoding the current colour is not necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\redub}{}
\def\redub#1{%
  \@ifnextchar_%
    {\@redub{#1}}
    {\@latex@warning{Missing argument for \string\redub}\@redub{#1}_{}}%
}
\def\@redub#1_#2{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    \color{red}%
    \underbrace{\color{currentcolor}#1}_{\color{red}#2}%
    \color{currentcolor}%
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
{
\color{blue} % only to demonstrate 1. and 2. (see the top of my answer)
A simple example:
\[
    \redub{Ax=b}_{\mathclap{\text{my linear system}}}
\]
blah blah blah\ldots \\[1em]
}

A more involved example
\[
    \redub{\partial _t(m_x m_yHu)}_{\mathclap{\text{Local acceleration}}}
    {+}
    \redub{\partial_x(m_yHuu) + \partial_y(m_xHvu) + \partial_z(m_xm_ywu)}_%
    {\text{Advective acceleration}}
    {-}
    \redub{m_xm_yf_cHv}_{\substack{\text{Coriolis}\\\text{acceleration}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Jubobs Thanks for this. It will be very useful to me as I have to write several equations.

Comment: Why some text have `\mathclap` in front and some don't? What does it do?

Comment: @LWZ It prevents extra space on either side of the maths stuff passed as the first argument of `\underbrace`. Try to remove the `\mathclap` command, leaving simply the text as the second argument to `\underbrace` and you'll see what happens. See the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) documentation for more detail.

Comment: Now I tested this in my `beamer` slides. I notice that this method affects font size. The terms with `\underbrace` becomes smaller than normal.

Comment: @LWZ Perhaps, but what you describe has little to do with the approach I use to get coloured underbraces or the document class you use;  that's the normal behaviour of `\underbrace`. See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30091/21891) for more detail on how to scale the font of `\underbrace`'s arguments.