# Highlighting subscripts/superscripts in math mode

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

This is an extension of [Highlight terms in equation mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118410/highlight-terms-in-equation-mode),

The problem is, with

```
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
\colorbox{red!50}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
```

In, `$x^{\highlight{\alpha}}$`, `\alpha` is enlarged abnormally, unlike a proper superscript.

Is there a way to highlight specific variables within math-mode whilst maintaining subscripts and superscripts?

Comment: Does `\scriptsize\alpha` work for you?

Comment: `$a^{\highlight{\scriptsize\alpha}}` does not work

Comment: `$a^{\scriptsize\highlight{\alpha}}$`, maybe? It works here.

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! Stay safe ❤️

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\highlight` command doesn't work in superscripts because (1) the equation in the `\colorbox` doesn't know it's supposed to be typeset in `\scriptstyle` and (2) because of the `\displaystyle` in its definition explicitly telling TeX to typeset `#1` in display style (using a full size font and things like large summation/integral symbols).

This is pretty much exactly what the `\mathpalette` command is designed to solve.
A detailed description of how `\mathpalette` works can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/156366).

Here is a simple re-implementation that uses `\mathpalette.
(An improved version may be found below)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\mathpalette\highlightwithstyle{#1}}
\newcommand{\highlightwithstyle}[2]{\colorbox{red!50}{$#1#2$}}

\begin{document}

\[
    a^{\highlight{\alpha}} + \highlight{\sum}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

What `\highlight{\alpha}` now does is expand to `\highlightwithstyle{<current math style>}{\alpha}`, where `<current math style>` is either `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` (whichever is appropriate). This in turn turns into

```
\colorbox{red!50}{$\scriptstyle\alpha$}
```

when used in a super-/subscript, and into

```
\colorbox{red!50}{$\displaystyle\alpha$}
```

when used in the main display equation etc. (The other two cases are `\textstyle` for inline equations and `\scriptscriptstyle` for nested super-/subscripts.)

---

### Addendum (improved version)

Here is another version of the same command that creates a slightly tighter box and doesn't in most (but not all) circumstances affect the spacing of your equation.
It also lets you specify a colour.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\highlight}[2][red!50]{\mathpalette{\highlightwithstyle[#1]}{#2}}
\newcommand{\highlightwithstyle}[3][red!50]{
  \begingroup                         %% <- limit scope of \box0 and \fboxsep assignment
    \sbox0{$\mathsurround 0pt #2#3$}% %% <- typeset content in box 0
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5pt}        %% <- set (smaller) framebox margins
    \sbox2{\hspace{-.5pt}%            %% <- create box 2, undo margin
      \colorbox{#1}{\usebox0}%        %% <- print the contents of box 0 in a \colorbox
    }%
    \dp2=\dp0 \ht2=\ht0 \wd2=\wd0     %% <- set dimensions of box 2 to match box 0
    \box2                             %% <- print box 2
  \endgroup                           %% <- revert old definitions of the boxes and \fboxsep
}

\begin{document}

\[
    a^{\highlight{\alpha}} + \highlight{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\fbox{1}}{\color{blue}k!}} + \frac{\highlight[green]{x}}{2}
\]
\[
    a^{\alpha} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\fbox{1}}{\color{blue}k!} + \frac{x}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I've tried to explain what each of these lines do in the comments, except for `\mathsurround`.
Setting `\mathsurround` to `0pt` does nothing here, but it would matter if your document uses non-standard spacing around inline equations (which is unlikely).

Comment: I've added an improved version of `\highlight` that allows you to choose a colour and shouldn't affect spacing in most circumstances.